# ScriptManager and EnablePartialRendering

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

I have a page that uses ajax  scripmanager > progressupdate so I can display the user a message of "Loading, wait..".  Now, my question is the following.  I have the EnablePartialRendering set to true, mainly because if I set it to false my panel with the loading stuff doesn't display.
When is set to true, then if I want to set the text and visibility on a row that is normally set to visible=false, it just doesn't happen.  My row doesn't show.
My "Loading" message will only display if a stored procedure exist, if it doesn't I just need to let the user know.

Any suggestions?

Comment: could you please post some code?

Comment: Are you calling `Update()` on the panel after changes by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code from my .aspx page

.
.

```
                     </asp:GridView>
                 </ContentTemplate>
               </asp:UpdatePanel>
           </asp:Panel> 

           <asp:Panel ID="pnlUpdate" runat="server" >
                <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" >
                    <ProgressTemplate>

                    <div id="progressBackgroundFilter"></div>
                    <div id="processMessage" align="center" style="color:#cc0000"> Please, wait while processing...<br /><br />
                         <asp:Image ImageUrl="images/loading.gif" runat="server" ID="loading_gif" />
                    </div>

                   </ProgressTemplate>
                </asp:UpdateProgress>
            </asp:Panel> 

        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>        
    <asp:TableRow ID="Row_Error"  Visible="false">
        <asp:TableCell CssClass="GVI">&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="labelError"  runat="server" Text=""/>&nbsp;                                      </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell CssClass="GvItmR">
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2"ForeColor="Green" Text="Go Back" NavigateUrl="~/Menu.aspx" runat="server"/>&nbsp;
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
```

The Row_Error row is where I want to display a message.

Comment: Monica, if you want to add additional information you may edit your post and add to it.

Comment: <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"  AsyncPostBackTimeOut="600" EnableHistory="true" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnablePageMethods="true" />